# Rxjava window() confusing results

Tags: rx-java

I'm learing rxjava at the moment and get stuck with a window operator. I'm testing the following simple code on my android device and getting confusing results.

Code:

```
Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .take(10)
    .window(250, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .flatMap(o -> o.toList())
    .subscribe(o -> Log.d(TAG, "object: "+o));
```

Sometimes, I get what is looks like right results for me:

```
object: [0, 1]
object: [0, 1, 2]
object: [1, 2, 3]
object: [2, 3, 4]
object: [3, 4, 5]
object: [4, 5, 6]
object: [5, 6, 7]
object: [6, 7, 8]
object: [7, 8, 9]
object: [8, 9]
object: [9]
```

But sometimes, I get something like

```
object: [0, 1]
object: [0, 1, 2]
object: [1, 2, 3]
object: [2, 3, 4]
object: [3, 4, 5]
object: [4, 5, 6]
object: [6, 7]
object: [6, 7, 8]
object: [7, 8, 9]
object: [8, 9]
object: [9]
```

Could anyone explain why results are different for this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code does not execute in no time. As you can see from the logs there are small differences in emitting onNext event so it is not equal exactly multiplicity of 100 milliseconds. If you add window operator gaps are even bigger. In this code there is a boundary case that might cause unwanted behavior if onNext event hits wrong window

```
Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .doOnNext(new Action1<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Long aLong) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ON NEXT TIME    " + System.currentTimeMillis() % 10000);
            }
        })
        .take(10)
        .window(250, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object aLong) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SUBSCRIBE TIME: " + System.currentTimeMillis() % 10000);
            }
        });
```

Logs without window operator

```
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    8445
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 8445
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    8545
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 8545
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    8646
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 8646
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    8745
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 8745
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    8846
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 8846
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    8945
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 8945
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    9045
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 9045
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    9145
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 9146
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    9245
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 9245
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    9345
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 9345
```

Logs with window operator

```
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    7622
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 7718
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    7722
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 7818
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    7822
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 7918
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    7922 // THIS
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 8018
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    8023 // COMPARE WITH THIS
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 8118
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    8122
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 8218
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    8223
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 8319
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    8323
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 8419
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    8422
SOME_TAG: SUBSCRIBE TIME: 8518
SOME_TAG: ON NEXT TIME    8522
```